# How can I remove a button from a Screen using Ruby Motion

Tags: uibutton, rubymotion, superview

I can manage to remove an image

```
def remove_image
    @button_image.removeFromSuperview
end
```

But what script works in order to remove a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A button is a subclass of a `UIView` so you can remove it the same way:

```
@button.removeFromSuperview
```

Alternatively, you can just hide the button:

```
@button.hidden = true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not think it would be that easy. 